# Android SDK API 33 - Unknown attribute android:textAllCaps

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I updated my project with new SDK which is Android API 33. I checked that the `attr` for `textAllCaps` is an `Unknown attribute android:textAllCaps`.

This is Android Studio Settings

[image]

This is for SDK Tools

[image]

Here is the `TextView`

[image]

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_paid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/paid"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Here is the `attrs.xml` file with the file location

[image]

**Question**

How to fix this unknown attribute?

Comment: checked yes it showing the same in addition, in manifest setting like android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
         android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" als o showing same unknown attribute message. However, all are working android:textAllCaps = false/true both working. I changed it to app:textAllCaps than no such message.

Comment: @tintin I have tried to use `app:textAllCaps`, but the result `cannot find declaration to go`

Comment: It's an issue on SDK 33. For the moment the only solution is to downgrade to SDK 32 and wait for next release (which is supposed to be final version)

Comment: Did you find any solution beside downgrading to 32? Thanks

Comment: ATM, I just downgrading to 32 ... @MarkDelphi

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I did the same. I always use the latest versions. There are new versions of `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0-alpha05` and `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha05` that require the 33.

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I have created a request on [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242306733).

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your effort sir. I hope this issue will solve soon. @MarkDelphi

Comment: Same issue in Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2 for android:contentDescription (which is quite funny, I only added those because the layout editor was nagging - damned if you do and damned if you don't...)

Comment: @PeteBaron welcome to Android Studio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241460885#comment8):

> Fixed in Studio Dolphin.
>
> It is not possible to back port the fix to Chipmunk.

[Android Studio Dolphin](https://developer.android.com/studio) is now stable.