# Why Android Studio tips: Unknown attribute android:paddingHorizontal in android api 33

Tags: android, xml

When i updates my android project targetSdkVersion to 33, in xml i get this tip

Unknown attribute android:paddingHorizontal
Inspection info: This inspection highlights unknown XML attributes in Android resource files and AndroidManifest.xml

it's not a problem. my android project still working.

Comment: Same here https://stackoverflow.com/q/72654174/9346054