# XML suggestions are not showing in target version 33 or compile version 33

Tags: android, xml, gradle, targetsdkversion

My issue is that when I change target version `33` or compile version `33` and start layout design in `XML` then suggestions are not shown, but suggestions are also working in target version `32` or compile version `32`

```
android {
    compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sketch"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        ...
    }
}
```

- after or before targetSdk and compileSdk version.

| SDK Version `32 or below` | SDK Version `33` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: SDK Version 32] | [image: SDK Version 33] |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android SDK API 33 - Unknown attribute android:textAllCaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72654174/android-sdk-api-33-unknown-attribute-androidtextallcaps)

Comment: @Ticherhaz FreePalestine, that is my issue then what is the problem with sdk version and how can i got suggestions in sdk `33`